# model doesnt train and outputs the same class

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Let me give you some background

Dataset:

https://www.kaggle.com/dionyshsmiaris/xrays which includes Xrays of class:

```
0/"normal" (1227 xrays)
1/"pneumonia_cause_viral_infection" (2238)
?/"pneumonia_cause_bacteria" (1207)
```

**import data:**

```
train_dir = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Xraydataset/train_images/"
test_dir =  "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Xraydataset/test_images/"
def get_data(folder):
  X = []
  y = []
  for image_filename in tqdm(os.listdir(folder)):#/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Xraydataset/train_images/   == folder
    img_file = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(folder + '/' + image_filename,color_mode="grayscale")
    if img_file is not None:
      img_file=img_file.resize((224,224),1) 
  #img_file = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.smart_resize(img_file, (224, 224)) #256 256 1?
  #img_file = scipy.misc.imresize(arr=img_file, size=(150, 150, 3))
      img_arr = np.asarray(img_file)
      X.append(img_arr)
  label=pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Xraydataset/labels_train.csv',usecols = ['class_id'])
  # y.append(label)
  X = np.asarray(X)
  y = np.asarray(label)

  return X,y
X_train, y_train = get_data(train_dir)
X_test, y_test= get_data(test_dir)
```

**Preprocessing :**

```
X_train=np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=3)
X_test=np.expand_dims(X_test, axis=3)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32') / 255
X_test = X_test.astype('float32') / 255

X_train_mean = np.mean(X_train, axis=0)
X_train -= X_train_mean
X_test -= X_train_mean

print('x_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

xtrain=X_train[:3700]
ytrain=y_train[:3700]
#split data to train and test
xtest=X_train[3700:]
ytest=y_train[3700:]


t_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(ytrain, 3)
t_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(ytest, 3)
```

**DataGen:**

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
        samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
        zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
        rotation_range = 30,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        zoom_range = 0.2, # Randomly zoom image 
        width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        horizontal_flip = True,  # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=False)  # randomly flip images
datagen.fit(xtrain)
```

**Compile:**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32 , (3,3) , strides = 1 , padding = 'same' , activation = 'relu' , input_shape = (224,224,1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2) , strides = 2 , padding = 'same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64 , (3,3) , strides = 1 , padding = 'same' , activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2) , strides = 2 , padding = 'same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64 , (3,3) , strides = 1 , padding = 'same' , activation = 'relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2) , strides = 2 , padding = 'same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128 , (3,3) , strides = 1 , padding = 'same' , activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2) , strides = 2 , padding = 'same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256 , (3,3) , strides = 1 , padding = 'same' , activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2) , strides = 2 , padding = 'same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 128 , activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units = 3 , activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer = "Adam" , loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

**Learning rate, training**

```
learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_accuracy',
                                            patience = 2, 
                                            verbose=1,
                                            factor=0.3,
                                            min_lr=0.000001)

history = model.fit(datagen.flow(xtrain,t_train, batch_size = 32) ,shuffle=True,
                    epochs = 20 , validation_data =datagen.flow(xtest,t_test), 
                    callbacks = [learning_rate_reduction])
```

Output:

```
[[0.276 0.455 0.27 ]
 [0.291 0.423 0.286]
 [0.286 0.434 0.28 ]
 ...
 [0.288 0.43  0.282]
 [0.292 0.429 0.28 ]
 [0.289 0.427 0.284]]
```

typical acc is around 46% and validation acc 49% but thats because it predicts the class with the most frequency

also the loss is almost the same so i assume that it doesnt train any tips/help

Edit:(with class_weights = {0: .9837, 1: .5394, 2: 1.0})

```
Epoch 1/20
116/116 [==============================] - 19s 154ms/step - loss: 0.8551 - accuracy: 0.3216 - val_loss: 1.1174 - val_accuracy: 0.3302
Epoch 2/20
116/116 [==============================] - 18s 155ms/step - loss: 0.8587 - accuracy: 0.3265 - val_loss: 1.1073 - val_accuracy: 0.3261
Epoch 3/20
116/116 [==============================] - 18s 158ms/step - loss: 0.8554 - accuracy: 0.3330 - val_loss: 1.1114 - val_accuracy: 0.3241
.
.
.
Epoch 18/20
116/116 [==============================] - 18s 155ms/step - loss: 0.8585 - accuracy: 0.3208 - val_loss: 1.1097 - val_accuracy: 0.3251
Epoch 19/20
116/116 [==============================] - 18s 154ms/step - loss: 0.8556 - accuracy: 0.3378 - val_loss: 1.1084 - val_accuracy: 0.3395
Epoch 20/20
116/116 [==============================] - 18s 156ms/step - loss: 0.8562 - accuracy: 0.3422 - val_loss: 1.1127 - val_accuracy: 0.3364
```

output :

```
[[0.333 0.345 0.322]
 [0.361 0.283 0.356]
 [0.319 0.343 0.338]
 ...
 [0.335 0.329 0.335]
 [0.439 0.179 0.383]
 [0.338 0.311 0.351]]
```

From what i get now my model is able to guess all three classes but it is not learning if u look at loss it is staying the same and acc is around 30-33% which would result to random guess any tips?

Comment: Higher Learning Rate, Larger Neural Network, Transfer Learning, Train for longer epochs,  Larger batch size.

Comment: Ok all of them are good sugestions i have tried training on longer epochs /larger bacth size/ Larger Neural Net  without any impact on the results i guess i will try higher learning rate and i dont want to use transfer learning because i want to build from scratch.also thanks for your time @NiteyaShah

Comment: @NiteyaShah neither does higher learning rate.

Comment: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2020/06/deep-learning-detecting-pneumonia-x-ray-images.html Can you try this architecture ? If it works then we know that your architecture isnt capable enough and if it doesn't there is something wrong with your data pipelines.

Comment: @NiteyaShah i will give it a shot but this architecture is about 2 classes.wont that be a problem with my dataset?

Comment: It may give slightly better results or not. Even if it does give slightly better results, then we know that the model complexity is the issue. If the issues still remain, then a closer look into the dataset is warranted.

Comment: @NiteyaShah i tried it same results

Comment: Then I believe the answer below about unbalanced classes is the best way forward.

Comment: @NiteyaShah working on it will let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code and ran it and got the same results you did. To see if the model was the issue I modified the code to use transfer learning with Resnet. Got essentially the same results. I went to Kaggle to see if there were any notebooks with better result. There are no notebooks. I think the problem is with the dataset. There is an alternate data set you might use on Kaggle at https://www.kaggle.com/bachrr/covid-chest-xray. Also there is this data set https://www.kaggle.com/paultimothymooney/chest-xray-pneumonia

Comment: well the dataset is from a competition and people getting to 84% so i guess there is a way to fix its issue but thank you for your help i will try balancing the classes next.

Comment: that was going to be my next recommendation. The class counts were  0 =1227, 1=2238 and , 2 = 1207 so the class weights are {0: .9837,  1: .5394,  2: 1.0}

Comment: where did you see notebooks with 84% I see no notebooks listed except the starter notebook

Comment: by the way you do not need to do datagen.fit(xtrain). This is only needed if you are setting  featurewise_center, or  samplewise_center or  featurewise_std_normalization     or   samplewise_std_normalization or     zca_whitening to true.

Comment: it is a private competition of my college